# Startup script doesn't work

Tags: linux, services, webmin

I have the following start script.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# MyApp
#
# description: bla bla

case $1 in
    start)
        /bin/bash /javaprog/serport-start.sh
    ;;
    stop)
        /bin/bash /javaprog/serport-stop.sh
    ;;
    restart)
        /bin/bash /javaprog/serport-stop.sh
        /bin/bash /javaprog/serport-start.sh
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

The problem is it doesn't start automatically (Webmin tells me that it should be, in the column "at boot?" it's marked as "yes").

If I start the script in Webmin by clicking on "start now" it works and the script starts.

Does someone know what the problem can be?

Comment: What's the underlying distro of Linux you're running Webmin on?

Comment: I am running it on a raspberry pi the disto is Raspbian (debian)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest going through the Webmin Wiki, there is a topic titled: [Bootup and Shutdown](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/BootupAndShutdown). You typically have to include special comments at the top so that your script gets picked up as being a well-formed startup script.

[image: ss of script]

Specifically notice the init comment lines:

[image: ss of init]